# Can't use "network_mode" in docker-compose.yml file version 3 with docker-compose v1.24.1

Tags: docker, docker-compose

When I try to docker-compose my docker-compose.yml file with "network_mode", I receive the following error:

> ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
>   services.combined.network_mode contains an invalid type, it should be
>   a string

**My docker-compose.yml file:**

```
version: '3'
services:
    dbrs:
        hostname: localhost
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: ./docker/dbrs/Dockerfile
        volumes:
            - dbdata:/data/db
        ports:
            - "27017:27017"
            - "27018:27018"
            - "27019:27019"
        networks:
            - app-network

    combined:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: ./docker/combined/Dockerfile
        env_file: .env
        ipc: host
        volumes:
            - .:/home/node/app
            - ./cypress:/usr/src/app/cypress
            - node_modules:/home/node/app/node_modules
            - /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix
            - /dev/shm:/dev/shm
        ports:
            - "5000:5000"
            - "8080:8080"
        networks:
            - app-network
        network_mode:
            - "service:dbrs"
        depends_on:
            - dbrs

networks:
    app-network:
        driver: bridge

volumes:
    dbdata:
    node_modules:
```

As far as I'm aware, network_mode should be available for version 3 per [the docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/). My docker-compose version is 1.24.1, build 4667896.

**Is there any other reason why I can't use "network_mode" in my docker-compose.yml file?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you say:

```yaml
network_mode:
  - "service:dbrs"
```

The new line, hyphen declares a YAML list.  As the error message notes, this needs to be a single string and not a list; the value should be on the same line.

```yaml
network_mode: "service:dbrs"
```

(It's pretty unusual to directly connect to another service's network stack like this.  If you need to communicate with the other container, you can use its Compose service name and internal port number, `dbrs:27017`.  [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) has more details.)